# Invoke Func<T, TResult> from Reflection

Tags: c#

Finally, I have been able to get through reflection, a member of type `Func<T, TResult>`, now, how do I invoke it?

When I retrieve it, I do it through the **Type.GetMembers** method, and that returns a **MemberInfo** type that does not have a **Invoke** method; how can I invoke it?

Again people, thanks in advance! =)

Comment: Do you already have an object of type `Func<T, TResult>`, or do you need to get it from a field or property?

Comment: I already have it, I just need to invoke once I retrieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get a delegate to the method you need to call `MakeGenericMethod` passing in the generic type arguments - this returns an invokable delegate:

```
var constructedMethod 
    = yourMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int), typeof(string));
constructedMethod.Invoke(yourInstance, yourArguments);
```

If you are curious, the reason you need to do this is because the `MethodInfo` instance you currently hold is *open*, meaning that no generic type arguments have been bound to it (and naturally this method cannot be invoked which is why there is no `Invoke` method available).   By calling `MakeGenericMethod` you are explicitly constructing the method with generic type arguments.

For reference - [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx):

> [Returns] a MethodInfo object that represents
>   the constructed method formed by
>   substituting the elements of
>   typeArguments for the type parameters
>   of the current generic method
>   definition.

Comment: I think he already has an instance of `Func<T, TResult>`, he just needs to call it

Comment: @thecoop - Yes, but the OP cannot invoke anything until generic type arguments have been supplied which is why `MakeGenericMethod` will solve the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Once you've got an instance of `Func<T, TResult>`, you can cast it to a `Delegate`, and call the [`DynamicInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx) method on it which allows you to call the delegate in a reflection scenario (as long as the argument types match!)

Answer (score 1):

> When I retrieve it, I do it through the **Type.GetMembers** method, and that returns a **MemberInfo** type that does not have a **Invoke** method; how can I invoke it?

Cast the object to the type `MethodInfo` -- this does have an Invoke method.

Alternatively, if this is a field or property, you will have to obtain the value using reflection and then cast that to the appropriate delegate type, which you can then invoke.